# Selling a home while Canada Disability

Tags: canada, home, house-sale, disability

My friend on disability and want to sell my house and buy a smaller one. They will profit from the sale but will put that money into a new house. Will this count as income and mess up my disability?
I keep hearing different things. Seems like if it does you really can't afford to move

Comment: When you say "on disability", which benefits in particular are you asking about?

Comment: It's a medical disability. They can not work because of a chronic illness.

Comment: This question really isn't clear, it sometimes talks about a "friend" and "they" and sometimes about "I" and "my". It's fine if you want to make the question about "My friend" to keep it hypothetical / anonymous but I genuinely can't tell if there's one person involved here or two ("me" and "my friend"). If there are multiple people involved the situation almost certainly gets more complex.

Comment: It is for a friend. I actually live in the USA and she lives in Saskatchewan. She also has 2 young kids. I visit several times a year.

Comment: @troy OK, so the friend wants to sell *her* house and is worried about *her* disability benefits? Do you have any stake in the house or her other financial affairs?

Comment: No I have no stake in it at all. I just care about them